# angular 2: what's host: {class} used for?

Tags: angular

I have seen this code before and wondering what role the host > class > comment plays, as in:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ngc-comment',
  host: { 
    class: 'comment'  // <--------- ??
  },
  template,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It adds the `comment` CSS class to the host element, i.e. the `<ngc-comment>` element, in this case.

So, whenever you use the component in a template, and thus have something like

```
<ngc-comment></ngc-comment>
```

Angular will transform it to

```
<ngc-comment class="comment"></ngc-comment>
```